# My computer is eating hard drives

Tags: hard-drive, troubleshooting

About a year and a half ago I built my computer, and I was knowledgeable enough to put it together but definitely not to troubleshoot all of the issues it's had. A few months ago the 2TB Seagate hard drive failed slowly but surely until the computer didn't work at all. I blamed it on a faulty hard drive and sent it in to be replaced. The issues started with the computer freezing up and only recovering when I powered off and then on again.

So I purchased an SSD of another make and installed that. However recently the computer is showing similar signs to the beginning of my last hard drive failure, so I suspect it's not the drive but something else. Any advice on what to check/do?

Comment: I do not think it is a drive issue. You can check SMART information. SSD's die another way.

Comment: Was the first drive SSD also?

Comment: It looks like overheat or other hardware problem (power, MB. memory). You can run memtest from grub menu.

Comment: @hbdgaf: Has Seagate released a 2TB SSD yet?

Comment: @hbdgaf It doesn't look like it. The asker has been careful to specify what type he/she had.

Comment: You should monitor your power supply. I'm somewhat sensitive about it at the moment, because I've had a couple of hard disk problems and I am quite sure the problem was there. My problem wasn't even the power supply but the motherboard connector. I reseated the connector, voltages improved dramatically, and no problems since. I ran the manufacturer's repair software, and still using the same drive.

Comment: Your question contains conclusions rather than observations, making it impossible to diagnose your problem. For example, you say "the hard drive failed slowly". Presumably you drew that conclusion based on some observations, but you don't tell us what you observed that suggested that the hard drive was at fault. So we can't tell whether your diagnosis was accurate or not.

Answer (score 0):

For some suggestions about different ways to troubleshoot freezing that is caused by a hardware issue see: [Why did Ubuntu and Windows start hanging mysteriously after I took a vacation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154072/why-did-ubuntu-and-windows-start-hanging-mysteriously-after-i-took-a-vacation). This is a good hardware issue troubleshooting question because the freezing in the question occurred on both Windows and Ubuntu.

Although none of the answers to the linked question mention it, freezing can also be caused by a bad graphics card. If there is a problem with the graphics card, then anything related to graphics processing can have a problem too, including all activity on the screen freezing.

To check if your graphics card is using the recommended proprietary graphics driver, open the terminal and type:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

The easiest way to check if a discrete graphics card is causing problems is to temporarily remove it from the computer and connect the monitor cable to the motherboard.